# Spring Boot - Spring Security - Multiple configurations

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, basic-authentication

I try desperately to configure Spring Security in a Spring Boot application this way :

- One way with custom token for all services called by the application
- One way with HTTP Basic only for REST API services that will be used by another application

The combination of the two ways causes problems...

I tried multiples solutions without any success. I read this section : http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity

My code looks like this :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

// Function called by application
http.authorizeRequests(). antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "MyFunction").hasAnyRole("USER");

http.addFilterBefore(xAuthTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

// Function API REST
http.antMatcher("/api/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();

// Requests blocked by default
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().denyAll();

}
```

Adding httpbasic() causes "Security filter chain: no match" for my first function.
Do you have any idea of the right syntax... ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same requirements but with different authentication schemes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908946/spring-security-oauth2-and-form-login-configuration/30666550#30666550

Comment: The example in Spring Security documentation was correct. I didn't respect correctly the order. It fixes my problem.